# How to create an event button

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a project. Basically, there is a big grid square and inside of it, there are lots of little squares. When users move their mouse over these little squares they turn into black. However, I want to create a clear button that turns the color of these squares into their original color. I have a code but it doesn't work. I can turn their color into black but I cannot create an event button which clears everything.

Alter the code, tried different methods.

```
//set values
let tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');
let buttons = document.getElementsById('clearbutton');


//make  squares black using mouseover event   
  if(black){  
  for (const tile of tiles) {
    tile.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      tile.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    });
  }
}


//turn squares background-color into their original color
for (const cbutton of clearbutton) {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      tiles.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    });
  }
```

```
<nav id="navbar">
<ul>
  <li><button id = "clearbutton" type="button" style= "width: 200px; height; 150px; background-color: #99CCFF;">Clear</button></li>
</ul>
</nav>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
```

getElementById is not a function.

Comment: It's [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getelementbyid) not `getElementsById`, but it looks like you should be using classes for the buttons too.

Comment: I've changed it but this time I get the error of clearbutton is not iterable.

Comment: There are a number of syntax errors, not just the extra `s` in `getElementById`. For example, you have `lets buttons ...` but then you never reference `buttons`.

Comment: @tosyn — That's because it is **a** button and not **a list** of button**s**. Just use it. Don't loop over all the things in it.

Comment: Please create a MWE to show your problem using a Code Snippet

Comment: ```
clearbutton.addEventListener('mouseover',e => {
  tile.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
});
```

I've changed my code into this but this time i get the error of : Uncaught TypeError: clearbutton.addEventListener is not a function

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code below**

```js
let tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');
let clearbutton = document.getElementById('clearbutton');

if (black) {
    for (const tile of tiles) {
        tile.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
            tile.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        });
    }
}

clearbutton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    for (const tile of tiles) {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    }
});
```

**Here is a full working example**

```js
var black = true;

let tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');
let clearbutton = document.getElementById('clearbutton');

if (black) {
    for (const tile of tiles) {
        tile.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
            tile.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        });
    }
}

clearbutton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    for (const tile of tiles) {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    }
});
```

```css
.newDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<button id="clearbutton">Clear All</button>
<div id="container">
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
</div>
```